# Not able to pin my application to Start on Lumia 900

Tags: lumia-900, outlook

I'm not able to pin my **Outlook Inbox** to my home page on my Lumia 900! All other apps pin just fine except this one. Is there a quick way for me to access my Outlook? When I keep the Outlook app pressed, the `Pin to start` option is grayed out unlike other apps.

**EDIT**: I did the following after numerous Google searches online. Still nothing!

1. On Start, flick left to the App list.
2. Tap Outlook, and then tap More `...`
3. Tap folders, and then tap show all folders
4. Tap and hold the inbox, and then tap `pin to start`

I always get a grayed out box `pin to start`. This does **not** happen with any other app. What's going on here?

Comment: If you delete and re-add your Outlook account, does this still happen?

Comment: @JulianaPeña All I needed to do was restart my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to pin one of your folder to the home page; if this doesn't work, restart your phone.

Other than that, click the arrow to go to the full list of applications, press again in the same spot (so you press the first number/letter) and then select `O` such that the Outlook application is within reach.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get you. Do you mean *search* for the Outlook app each time? That's pretty inconvenient!

Comment: @prrao: It goes pretty quick, but that was an alternative suggestion. Did you try pinning a folder?

Comment: @prrao: When push a folder name for some time a menu will show up allowing you to pin it. Please note that you need to do this in the list of folders, not on the title of the current folder you are in.

Comment: @prrao: Huh, that would mean they are pinned already. Have you tried restarting the phone (turn off and on again)?

Comment: lol restarting worked. Don't know why only this folder needed a restart and not other app folders. Thanks! Could you edit your answer?

Comment: @prrao: Edited it in.

Comment: @TomWijsman Note: Outlook is one of those few applications that can be renamed. To rename, open app > tap `...` > tap `linked inboxes` > tap `rename linked inbox`. Therefore, you may not always find an Outlook option under the `O` section of the apps. I know I don't have one due to the rename. :)

Comment: @Thomas: And I don't have one because I am using Windows Live (I think), but have seen the Outlook app to be very similar (although they get flagging while I don't). Nice that it supports renaming, didn't know that...

Comment: @TomWijsman Sorry didn't mentioned this earlier. E-mail inboxes can be renamed ___only___ if they are linked with other inboxes.